# Automate config command in Git Bash with Python

Tags: python-2.7, automation, subprocess, git-bash

I want to automate these commands:

```
echo something 
git config --global user.name "myUser"
git config --global user.email "myMail@mail.com"
```

I did some research and saw this library in Python `subprocess`. But the following commands don't work:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["echo", "something"])
subprocess.call(["git", "config", "--global", "user.name", "\"myUser\""])
subprocess.call(["git", "config", "--global", "user.email", "myMail@mail.com"])
```

This is my ".bat" file, where I have the Python location and the script location:

```
@echo off
"C:\Python27\python.exe" -c "D:\Tools\Scripts\GIT_login.py"
pause
```

Unfortunately, when I run the ".bat" file, I get this message:

```
File "<string>", line 1
   D:\Tools\Scripts\GIT_login.py
    ↑
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the bat on git-bash, you need to give the python file path like this:
'D://Tools/Scripts/GIT_login.py'